# Can you call windows explorer in a batch and go to a file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, explorer

I do a lot of procedures where I have to open explorer and open 1-3 different paths - I want to launch explorer from running a batch file, and opening explorer to the right path - is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You can open an Explorer window from a command prompt by using...

```
explorer.exe full\path\to\directory
```

Or, you can open an Explorer window directly to a specific file in a directory using...

```
explorer.exe /select,\full\path\to\file
```

explorer.exe is found in `C:\Windows`, which should be on your `PATH` environment variable already, but I'm including this just for reference. If your path includes any spaces, then you'll have to enclose the path in double quotes e.g. `explorer.exe "path\with spaces\directory"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible.

```
cd C:\WINDOWS
Explorer.exe "Full_Path_here"
Explorer.exe "More_Path_here"
```

Don't forget the following :-

- The inverted commas covering Path
- Navigating to Windows folder
- Full path includes drive also.

Eg,

```
Explorer.exe "D:\Videos"
```

Comment: I think it works even without the .exe 
... is there a way to save the batch file to your task bar ?